# Swift 4 - CocoaMQTT not compatible anymore?

Tags: ios, swift4, mqtt

I completed a few months ago a project with CocoaMQTT.
Now I want to do a new project and I created the files like the one before.
Now I get this error-codes. 
When I click the button to update the Code, I get new error-codes. 
Got someone the same problem or know a solution?

[image: error-codes]

[image: error-codes_1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing Swift 3 and Swift 4 in your project. Because Swift 3 and Swift 4 are not source-compatible, this can not work. You need to either use Swift 3 for everything, or Swift 4 for everything.

For CocoaMQTT there is a Swift 4.2 version available since Oct 12, 2018.
SwiftyTimer looks abandoned, and there is no Swift 4 version of it yet (Oct 2018). It has been used by CocoaMQTT previously, but they have dropped that dependency with the new version. So there should be no problem once you upgrade CocoaMQTT, unless you are using SwiftyTimer yourself.

You will need to support Swift 4 eventually (if not now, then in 1 year maybe). Maybe you can get away with staying with Swift 3 for now..

Comment: PrintWatch is the name of my App. I created a new one, installed the pod again but it downloaded version 1.1.2 again. I feel stupid lol. How can I update MQTT?
Or how can I get back to Swift 3? 
Oh man these updates kill me every time

Comment: @TheAppment: Maybe you can ask another question on SO for why you cannot update to 1.1.3. Because I don't see any problem with that version. The new version [is registered in the public repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/f/e/9/CocoaMQTT/1.1.3/CocoaMQTT.podspec.json). I think updating that pod successfully would solve your problems. I wouldn't go back to Swift 3, because that would be only a temporary fix. (You can set the "Swift version" in the Xcode build settings for the target.)

Comment: You know what the problem is? I am a idiot. Instead of updating the pod, I installed the old version again and again..
Thank you!!!